# SQL Error on Calendar View with Relationships

Tags: views, 6, datetime

I have a calendar set up to show a date field from nodes that I get using relationships.

The relationship goes:

Application > Discipline > School > Date Field

In my view I get this error when attempting to use that date field as an argument in the Calendar:

```
user warning: Unknown column 'node_data_field_school_term_deadline.field_school_term_deadline_value' in 'where clause' query: SELECT DISTINCT node.nid AS nid, node.title AS node_title, node.created AS node_created, node_node_data_field_discipline_school_node_data_field_school_term_deadline.field_school_term_deadline_value AS node_node_data_field_discipline_school_node_data_field_school_term_deadline_field_school_term_deadline_value, node_node_data_field_discipline_school.nid AS node_node_data_field_discipline_school_nid, node_node_data_field_discipline_school.type AS node_node_data_field_discipline_school_type, node_node_data_field_discipline_school.vid AS node_node_data_field_discipline_school_vid, node.changed AS node_changed, node.type AS node_type FROM node node LEFT JOIN content_type_application node_data_field_application_discipline_id ON node.vid = node_data_field_application_discipline_id.vid INNER JOIN node node_node_data_field_application_discipline_id ON node_data_field_application_discipline_id.field_application_discipline_id_nid = node_node_data_field_application_discipline_id.nid LEFT JOIN content_type_discipline node_node_data_field_application_discipline_id_node_data_field_discipline_school ON node_node_data_field_application_discipline_id.vid = node_node_data_field_application_discipline_id_node_data_field_discipline_school.vid INNER JOIN node node_node_data_field_discipline_school ON node_node_data_field_application_discipline_id_node_data_field_discipline_school.field_discipline_school_nid = node_node_data_field_discipline_school.nid INNER JOIN users users ON node.uid = users.uid LEFT JOIN content_type_school node_node_data_field_discipline_school_node_data_field_school_term_deadline ON node_node_data_field_discipline_school.vid = node_node_data_field_discipline_school_node_data_field_school_term_deadline.vid WHERE ((node.status = 1) AND (node.type in ('application')) AND (users.uid = 1)) AND ((DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(node_data_field_school_term_deadline.field_school_term_deadline_value, '%Y-%m-%dT%T'), '%Y-%m') <= '2011-12' AND DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(node_data_field_school_term_deadline.field_school_term_deadline_value, '%Y-%m-%dT%T'), '%Y-%m') >= '2011-12')) ORDER BY node_changed ASC in /var/www/clients/client4/web39/web/sites/all/modules/views/includes/view.inc on line 799.
```

I'm not sure why it would be an unknown column. I don't know sql very well so I don't know where to begin when debugging this.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Have you recently deleted a field which name was `field_school_term_deadline` ? If so your view used it and is broken now, just remove it from the list of fields.

Comment: No, the field is still there. :(

Comment: Have you changed its frequency from 1 to unlimited ? Can you delete the relationship and build it again ?